# How to resolve Web API AmbiguousActionException in dotnet core web api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have two Get methods. I want to access this by using following urls

- https://localhost:44396/api/values/1
- https://localhost:44396/api/values/1?status=1

But I am trying to call this I am getting following exception

AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

```
     // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(SomeEnum id)
        {
           //somecode
            return "value";
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(SomeEnum id,int status)
        {


//somecode
            return "value";
        }
```

Is there any way to use routs like this with mutltiple get methods

Comment: What if you decide inside of action which method should be called? if you had int? status and its null you call other 'action/method'

Comment: `int status` requires the `[FromQuery]` attribute if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Regardless, I agree with Pribina that for one route you should have one action. Avoid using multiple actions by having all possible queries present and `nullable` and use logic to discern which subsequent methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing out of the box provided by ASP.NET core to help your case. As suggested in one of the comments, you should make the `status` parameter as `nullable` and use it within the action method to decide what next to do. Something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<string> Get(SomeEnum id,int? status)
{
    if(status == null)
    {    
        //perform usual logic which requires only id
    }
    else
    {
        //perform logic or call a method which requires both id and status
    }
    return "value";
}
```